# PHP curl not posting data

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to do a simple post to another page, but no data is posting. Anyone know what's wrong?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://example.com/test.php");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"one=val");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo print_r($result,true);
echo print_r(curl_getinfo($ch),true);
```

which results in:

```
(
    [url] => http://example.com/test.php
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )
    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

The headers wont print as well.

Comment: After running the script, what are the contents of `curl_error($ch)`?

Comment: @theftprevention Thanks, that showed a hostname issue. The server was behind a firewall I had to open up.